# Permission denied error when running VBScript via cscript.exe within PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, vbscript

I am trying to run a VBScript via `cscript.exe` within PowerShell (by invoking command on a remote server).

It keeps erroring out with a permissions error.

Below is the command that is failing.

```bsh
Invoke-Command -Computer testserver1 -ScriptBlock {
    Set-Location 'C:\Test1\Test2' |
        cscript.exe -NoLogo test_v1.03.vbs /anlyze:false /reboot:false
}
```

In above command I'm invoking a command to change the directory to where the VBScript is located and then run the VBScript via `cscript.exe`.

When I run the same command locally on the server in testserver1 it works fine, but when I invoke the same command on remote server, VBScript output file gives me a permission denied error.

> Error Report 2 - 70  Permission denied

My user has full access on remote servers and the local server from where I am invoking the command.

Is it `cscript.exe` or VBScript that is causing issue to me?

Comment: Why do you pipe `Set-Location` into `cscript.exe`? Is `/anlyze` a typo? Are you in a workgroup or a domain? What "VBScript output file"? What is the exact error message?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. set-location is used to reach to folder c:\test1\test2, 2- /anlyze is typo it should be analyze. 3- is in domain, where I have admin rights on all the servers. 4- vbscript is written to install patches on the server and create output file.